# unable to delete table row in php

Tags: php, mysql, html-table, row, delete-row

I'm having trouble with deleting table row in php.

> code

```
<form  action="<?php $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>" method="post"  >

<table>
<tr><td> About us text:</td></tr> 
<tr><td><textarea name="about_text" cols="100" rows="10">  </textarea></td></tr>

<tr><td align="right"><input type="submit"  value="Save" name="save" /></td></tr>

</table>

</form>
</div>
<br><br>
<table border="solid">
<th>Id</th><th>About Text</th><th>Edit</th><th>Delete</th>
<?php 
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC))

{
?>

<tr><td><?php echo(($row['about_id']))?></td><td><?php echo(($row['about_text']))?></td> <td><a href='edit.php'>Edit</a></td>
<td><a href=\"delete.php?id=".$row['about_id']."\">delete</a></td>

<?
}
?>
</table>
```

> delete.php

```
<?php 
incude('db');
mysqli_query("DELETE FROM about_us_tble WHERE ID=$GET(about_id)") 
or die(mysqli_error());
    echo"Data has been deleted";

header("location:about_admin.php")
?>
```

I am stuck in this simple probleam and have wasted lots of time to delete table row..

Comment: `ID=$GET(about_id)` nope

Comment: Buddy..You are missing a small `L` and `.php` extension too in your `include('db.php');` also your `mysqli` query is wrong at point where you are writting like this : `ID=$GET(about_id)` and also you are missing to mention your connection too in the query as `mysqli_query($con,"SELECT .....");` I would suggest to properly learn how to write it then you should write your code..! :D

Answer (score 0):

I think you are accessing to $_GET in the wrong way and you have the var in the query like a literal string ..

(warning to use direct input in query  .. eval how prepare the value in prper way  .. anyway fr the query )

```
<?php 
  include('db.php');
  mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM about_us_tble WHERE ID = '" .$_GET['id'] . "'")  or die(mysqli_error());
    echo"Data has been deleted";

  header("location:about_admin.php")
?>
```

Comment: missing something here

Comment: db connection, warning abut using user input directly in a query, `incude` spelling

Comment: For db connect i think in base on th include('db')

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't your `include` file has an extension, like:

And it is spelled `include` NOT **incude**

```
include('db.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Update this line in your delete.php

```
mysqli_query("DELETE FROM about_us_tble WHERE ID=$_GET['id']")
```